# CSS3: Box of unknown height in another Unknown-Height-Box with 100% Height

Tags: html, css

On my Website, there's a full-screen `background-image` (So it reaches from the bottom to the top, and from one site to the other). This image should be visible all the time, and never be hidden by any element other than images, etc.

I have three main parts:

1. Header
2. Content
3. Footer (fixed)

They have a transparent background, so my page background is visible through all of them. The Header and Footer have the same color (a darker one), and the Content-area is lighter.

The Header and Content are wrapped in a `<div>` element, the footer in a HTML5 `<footer>` element.
I use a fixed-position footer, and my Header and Content-Area are of undefined height.

I want the Content-Area to use the full height between Header and Footer.
Does anyone have any suggestions how to achieve this?

Code:

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
html, body {
 background-color: yellow;
 height: 100%;
}

#page_wrap {
 min-height: 100%;
 margin-bottom: -3em; /* footer height */
}
footer {
 background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
 line-height: 3em;
}

#head_nav {
 background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

#content {
 background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div id="page_wrap">
  <div id="head_nav">
   <p>Navigation</p>
   <a href="/">Home</a>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
   <p>The page content</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <footer>
  <p>Footertext</p>
 </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use DIV this way:

CSS:

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
html, body {
    background-color: yellow;
}

#page_wrap {
    height: 100%;
}
footer {
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  height: 50px;
}

#head_nav {
  height: 50px;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

#content {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 100px);
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j5u5pLvq/1/

Comment: But with this solution the user **always** has to scroll to see the footer. What I want is that the user only has to scroll, when there is so much content, that the footer goes under the fold. When there's not much content, the footer should end where the window ends, so it's _directly_ visible.

Comment: Yeah, but the Header now also has a fixed height. But anyways, I'll use it, thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped! If you are good to go with jQuery this can be another possible way: https://jsfiddle.net/j5u5pLvq/4/

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple considering that the height of footer is known to you as you have not mentioned that the height is unknown for footer.

So here's what you need to do:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset.css">
    <style>
        body{ font-size: 14px; font-family: verdana;}
        .container{ position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0; top: 0; bottom: 100px; }
        table{width: 100%;height: 100%;}
        .content{background-color: #E4FFF0;height: 100%;}
        footer{height: 100px;position: absolute; bottom: 0px; width: 100%; background-color: #aaa;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Container, it will have your header and content area -->
<div class="container">
   <!-- we need to include table to solve the variable header hight issue -->
   <table border="0" cell-spacing="0" cell-padding="0">
        <tr>
            <td class="header">
                <!-- header -->
                <header>header<br>header<br>header<br>header<br>header<br>header<br>header</header>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="content">
                <!-- content -->
                <section>content</section>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<footer>Footer Content</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

The above code snippet have a variable header, content area of full page height (expect the height of the footer) and a fixed footer.

Comment: Ok, this does the Job, so I'll use it for know. But is there a way to do this without using tables?

Comment: Looks like something worth attention, except that <table> tag is long time like deprecated for layout purposes. It may be a suitable time for flex solution :)

Comment: yup, `table` tag are almost deprecated for layout purposes but this piece of code works everywhere relatively to `Flex Box ` which is not fully supported in I.E / In old browsers.